# How to setup a logger with database information on django server start?

Tags: python, django, logging

Imagine that my application offers a logger configuration that is inputted by the user when the server is on (e.g. through an REST API resource).

Later on, when the server is shutted down and rebooted, I need that those configurations previously inserted are reflected on the logger (e.g. an handler that sends log through a TCP connection with a host, port, certs, etc)

One way to do this is to override ready() from AppConfig and load data from database to configure the logger properly at the beginning of the server start.

But from django documentation, they say that if you use this method to access the database may be dangerous as on this function even when you run manage.py test you will be accessing the production database.

So, how do I start the logger with configurations from database safely?

Maybe instead of storing logger configuration into database I could store it into a file on the system so django settings would be able to import them and I would split django settings into production and test.